# Calling Angulartics functions gives error

Tags: angularjs, angulartics

I want to use angulartics.
I have added "angulartics" and "angulartics.google.analytics"
But when I call $analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true); from my config function in app.js it gives me error.

Comment: have you included angulartics-ga.js too?

Comment: Yes I have included both "angulartics.min.js" and "angulartics-ga.min.js" from https://github.com/luisfarzati/angulartics/tree/master/dist but I couldn't find "ga('send', 'pageview'); " in the code and calling  $analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true); 
$analyticsProvider.withAutoBase(true);  from my app.js gives an error

Answer (score 0):

Solved it I had to add it as a name variable as well

myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$analyticsProvider', function($routeProvider,$analyticsProvider){
$analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true); $analyticsProvider.withAutoBase(true); 
....
}]);